# Android Creating application on Android using Android

Tags: android

I have a strange question...
I've got a netbook with Android 2.2 and i'm a developer.

is it possible to use android to write and compile applications? So write android application on android? it would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is not possible, unfortunatly. But I'd be happy to hear it is :)

Comment: Go ahead. If someone has not done it, do it.

Comment: I did some research but i don't find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). It allows you to write apps using pretty much the full capabilities of your device in a wide variety of languages.

The only thing is, these aren't full apps, so you couldn't distribute them using market, for example. But if you're looking to take full advantage of your netbook, it will let you hack some fun stuff together.

Answer (score 2):

You could now more recently try **[AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en)**. Listed below are some features pulled straight from the Play listing. All in a nice ICS style UI!

[image]

[image]

> Edit-compile-run cycle:
>
> - Create a sample App with a single click
> - Run your App with a single click
> - No root access required
> - Incremental compilation for fast build times
> - Uses Eclipse .classpath project format for compatibility
> - Integrated LogCat viewer Real-time error checking:
> - Real time error analyis throughout the whole project as you type
> - Automatic Quick-Fixes for many errors
>
> Refactoring:
>
> - Rename
> - Inline variable
> - Introduce variable
> - Extract method Code:
> - Code formatter
> - Organize imports
> - Out-comment code
> - Create setters/getters/constructors from fields
>
> Code Navigation:
>
> - Goto defintion
> - Find usages
> - Goto symbol
> - Goto class
>
> Editor:
>
> - Very fast editor even with large files
> - Code completion for Java and Android XML
> - Android online help directly from the code
> - Syntax highlighting for Java and XML
> - Unlimited Undo/Redo
> - Pinch zoom
> - Smart expand selection
> - Keyboard support with configurable keybindings
> - UI optimized for small screens to show as much code/content as possible
>
> Filebrowser:
>
> - Built-in file manager with the most common features: Rename, delete, create file or folder
> - Dropbox integration
> - Git integration with Commit/Dicard/Push/Pull and SSH support.

Answer (score 0):

To develop an application directly on an Android device you at least need a text editor (which is not a problem) and a port of the tools that are needed to build an apk (apkbuilder, zipalign). I don't believe there are ported versions of the tools. Thus it is unlikely possible to develop on a device directly. [App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/setup/index.html) looks promising but still requires some client software (and there is no Android version yet).

To conclude, no it is not possible to create an Android application on Android.